# Can’t boot after motherboard replacement

Tags: boot, bios, acpi, initramfs

My CPU broke and the CPU and motherboard were replaced on my DELL XPS 15 laptop. After this Xubuntu will not start. I need to somehow recover data in my home directory. GRUB is displaying and after I select Ubuntu, I get these error messages:

```
“PLD] , AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20160531/dswload2-316)

0.144971] ACPI Error: AELALREADY.EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (201805
31/psobject-221)

[ 0.144875] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Method (20160531/ps 1o0p-543)
[

0.144421] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\.8B.PC10,HC.RHUB.8S09.
_UPC), AELALREADYLEXISTS (20160591/dswload2-316)

T 0.144426) ACPI Error: AE_ALREADYLEXISTS, Ouring name lookup/catalog (201805
Si/psobject-221)

; 0.144430] ACPI Error: Skip panes opcode Method (20160531/ps1oop-543)

0.144484] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\.8B.PC10.xHC.RHUB.3309.
-PLD] , AE_LALREADYLEXISTS (201680591/dswload2-316)

T 0.244489) ACPI Error: AELALREADYLEXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (201605
Si/psobject-221)

: 0.144448] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Method (20160531/ps1o0p-543)

0.144488] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PC10.xHC.RHUB.3310.
UPC] , AE_LALREADYLERISTS (20180531/dswload2-316)

T 0.144494] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (201805
317psohject-221)

: 0.144498] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Method (20180531/psloop-543)

0.144502] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PC1I0.xHC.RHUB.S310-
PUD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20180531/dswload2-316)

C 0.144507] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (201805
31/psobject-221)
{ 0.144510] ACPI Error: Skip parsing opcode Method (20180531/psloop-543)
C 1.100186] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (2314) occurred attempting the self test
[ 3.810052] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
'f 3.810067] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
— Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
— Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
— Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; 1s /dev)
ALERT! WUUID=9c0f44be-ddef-4d25-8994-cbddab3ee685 does not exist.



Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) built-in shell (ash)
Enter “help* for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

How can I recover the data in my home directory?

Comment: Boot a live session and backup. Then reinstall.

Comment: I do not see the disk when booting with live on usb

Comment: So that's the problem that prevents booting. Check UEFI setting as you may need to change the sata mode as you did when installed the first time.

Comment: Ok! Yes i did, cant remember exactly what i did but i will try. Thank you

Comment: You may have more than one problem. Are you able to boot into Recovery Mode from the GRUB menu? TPM may need to be disabled, along with Secure Boot and Fast Start, in your BIOS. /etc/fstab may need to be edited, as the UUID may have some extraneous characters in it. You may also wish to check that you've got the latest BIOS in the new motherboard.

Comment: Im not able to boot in recovery mode. Ok

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, then mount the HDD, and see if you can locate /etc/fstab on the HDD, and show me what it looks like. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll probably miss them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled secure boot (dont know if it made any difference) and changed SATA operation from RAID to AHCI in BIOS and xubuntu is starting again.